# Load high resolution imageview android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

I've checked many scaleType options for android ImageView, but all of them results in a low quality image.

I use mipmap, which as I understand generates many sizes of the same image. 
Without setting the layouts to match_parent it loads the smallest version of the image. So can I load a higher mipmap size like x-hdpi or a similar approach to get a better image quality?

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:scaleType="fitCenter"
   android:src="@mipmap/logo_word"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mipmap folders are for placing your app icons in only. Any other drawable assets you use should be placed in the relevant drawable folders as before.

Comment: Thanks Luca, when I insert an image asset in Android studio, the images get inserted automatically in mipmap and I can only access it through @mipmap/logo_word not via @drawable ...

Comment: Why do you not create a drawable folder ?

Comment: It has a drawable folder, @Luca I think I get it now I should copy and paste the image to the drawable folder not through Android Studio > Insert Image Asset

Comment: select the image files, press shift / strg (I do not know just) and drag and drop it to a drawable folder